# How can I group related posts under 1 flag?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

Occassionally I stumble upon a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415053/user1415053) who obviously posts commercial plug/spam links. (in this case user spams link to http://www.hiqpdf.com/)

example 1:

> The [hiqpdf html to pdf](http://www.hiqpdf.com) converter converts perfectly any HTML with SVG to PDF. There is an [svg to pdf online demo](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx) where you can try

example 2:

> What language do you use in your website? For .NET the [hiqpdf html to pdf converter](http://www.hiqpdf.com) is imbatable. You can quickly [check it](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx) online to see how it actually performs.

It goes on like that in a similar pattern. I could flag them all seperately but I imagine that that just creates undue burden for the moderators since the correct course of action would be to delete the user and their posts in one go. (I did flag them right now to make sure they were noticed to be clear, using an identical text "user uses any pdf conversion question as an excuse to spam the same 2 links; all their posts follow identical pattern")

So can I:

- group all posts under 1 flag? (I did look but haven't found how)
- flag the user directly? (I only have 1.7K rep and didn't see an option to).

Comment: I wonder what imbatible means

Comment: unbeatable in bad english I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just flag one of the posts and explain the situation in the "Other" field.

Comment: ugh, that makes too much sense. __Real facepalm moment for me right now__